# How do you do a proper silent installation Miniconda3 with Windows PowerShell on Windows 10?

Tags: python, powershell, installation, miniconda

I try to install Miniconda via Powershell, and it works fine as long as the destination directory does not contain spaces, but unfortunately it does. Now, there are many, many posts on this topics and I tried to try out all the solutions, but in vain. Therefore, I have to still post ask what I do wrong here:

```
curl.exe --output Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe --url https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe
$minidir="$Env:ProgramFiles\Miniconda3"
Start-Process Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe -Wait -ArgumentList @('/S', '/InstallationType=JustMe', '/RegisterPython=1', '/D="$minidir"')
```

The problem lies in that `$Env:ProgramFiles` variable contains a space:

```
PS C:\> echo $Env:ProgramFiles
C:\Program Files
```

What I did not do is use a short-cut name for the directory without a space, because I am not sure if this is really good practice. I tried different variants of `` "`" `` and `", but unfortunately I was unsuccessful. The installation guide I followed can be found here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/ and I adapted the manual for Windows Command Prompt to Windows PowerShell. I would be extremely grateful, if someone could help me with the spacing problem, although it has been asked a lot before, because I just do not seem to see the error.`

EDIT: Thanks for @notjustme to insist. I need to precreate the working directory when using PowerShell, which was I am pretty sure not necessary with Windows Command Prompt.

```
curl.exe --output Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe --url https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe
$minidir="$Env:ProgramFiles\Miniconda3"
mkdir $minidir
Start-Process Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe -Wait -ArgumentList @('/S', '/InstallationType=JustMe', '/RegisterPython=1', '/D="$minidir"')
```

Comment: Do you have better luck if you run it with `"/D=$minidir"` instead of `'/D="$minidir"'`? In other words, replace single quotes with double quotes and lose the quotes entirely for $minidir.

Comment: @notjustme Unfortunately not. All combinations that I tried and were unsuccessful are:
"/D=$minidir",
'/D="$minidir"',
'/D=`"$minidir`"',
"/D=`"$minidir`"",
'/D="`"$minidir`""'.
So would be great if you have some other than these to try or if you could show me what works on your computer. There is of course a slight insecurity due to possible access rights problems because I use a company managed laptop, but I do not use Windows privately.

Comment: What is the actual error message you get and is PowerShell being run as Administrator? Also, the combination of `$Env:ProgramFiles\Miniconda3` and `/InstallationType=JustMe` seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @notjustme Unfortunately, running as Administrator makes no difference. The combination is not that counter-intuitive as the former represents a path on Windows whereas the / arguments are Windows Command Line Options, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options.

Comment: I wasn't puzzled about what they were, but `JustMe` as a target user and the "system-wide" path `$env:ProgramFiles` is counter-intuitive. `JustMe` in combination with an install path such as `$env:UserProfile` (as also is suggested in the documentation) would make more sense to me. `$env:ProgramFiles` would imply `AllUsers` is what I'm saying.

Comment: @notjustme Ok, so I changed JustMe to all Users but it did not work. Then I thought as a work-around I could cd into the directory that contains spaces and just use '\D=.\Miniconda3', but even that did not work, so apparently I need an absolut path for the directory, as relative paths apparently do not seem to work.

Comment: Any error messages in any of the scenarios described/tested so far?

Comment: Yes, when I want to use spaces in the /D argument always this error occurs:
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe -Wait -Argumen ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
When using relative paths, no errors occur.

Comment: @notjustme. Ah now it works! I need to use administrator shell and I need to pre-create the directory when using PowerShell, which I did not have to do when using Windows Command Prompt. Thank you very much!
PS C:\> $minidir="$Env:ProgramFiles\Miniconda3"
PS C:\> mkdir $minidir

    Directory: C:\Program Files


PS C:\ieu temp> Start-Process Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Windows-x86_64.exe -Wait -ArgumentList @('/S', '/InstallationType=AllUsers', '/RegisterPython=1', "/D=$minidir")